# apxldimg.sql is unable to open file

Tags: oracle

```
SYS> @apxldimg.sql c:\apex
```

SP2-0310: unable to open file "apxldimg.sql"

```
why this error from oracle sqlplus
```

Comment: did you run sqlplus in the OS directory in which your SQL file is located? if not, you would need to provide the full file path and not just the file name.

Comment: i have keep apex folder in c drive.

Comment: '''@apxldimg.sql c:\  or @apxldimg.sql c:\apex is not work "unable to open file"'''

Comment: You most likely need to give the complete path to the file: `@C:\path\to\file\apxldimg.sql c:\apex`

Comment: '''   @apex_epg_config.sql c:\apex     is not work "unable to open file"    '''''

Comment: oracle 21 version